# Import products in USD

Tags: import, currency

I have two stores setup in Magento, one is purely for US customers and it's currency is set to be USD.

I'm trying to import products so that the prices that are supplied are interpreted as US dollars, but when I import them, they are treated as GBP. Is it possible to import the prices in dollars?

Comment: Do you mean once they are imported they are showing as GBP and not USD? or are you asking how to convert prices on import?

Comment: I mean they are showing as GBP in the admin, and on the front end the GBP to USD conversion is taking place. I don't want this to happen though, I just want the import to consider the price in USD when it imports and the product prices under that store view to be in USD.

Comment: What are you using to import your products? Are you using a module to manage your currencies? Out of the box Magento does not calculate differences between currencies.

Comment: Just the standard CSV Import functionality. Could you recommend a module which would do the job? Are there any free ones? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When importing products the price is on the default currency.
The simplest way to overcome this is to change your import file prior to importing and multiply all the prices with the conversion rate.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the currency conversion rate would change so I don't think this is a long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the currency is set correctly on the store view that is assigned to US customers.

```
-->System -->Configuration -->Select Store View --> Currency Setup
```

Set  "Default Display Currency" and "Allowed Currencies" to "US Dollar" for this store view.

Comment: I have this already set up, the only place where the places are being displayed in USD is on the front end and there is a conversion taking place, from the price data that I have supplied into USD. I want the import to consider the prices dollars in the first place and not do any conversion, if that it is possible anyway?